# How do you split a pandas multiindex dataframe into train/test sets?

Tags: pandas, slice

I have a multi-index pandas dataframe consisting of a date element and an index representing store locations.  I want to split into training and test sets based on the time index.  So, everything before a certain time being my training data set and after being my testing dataset.  Below is some code for a sample dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import stats
data = stats.poisson(mu=[5,2,1,7,2]).rvs([60, 5]).T.ravel()
dates = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', freq='M', periods=60)
locations = [f'location_{i}' for i in range(5)]
df_train = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, locations]), columns=['eaches'])
df_train.index.names = ['date', 'location']
```

I would like `df_train` to represent everything before 2021-01 and `df_test` to represent everything after.

I've tried using `df[df.loc['dates'] > '2020-12-31']` but that yielded errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 'date' as an index, that's why your query doesn't work. For index, you can use:

```
df_train.loc['2020-12-31':]
```

That will select all rows, where df_train >= '2020-12-31'. So, if you would like to choose only rows where df_train > '2020-12-31', you should use df_train.loc['2021-01-01':]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `df.loc['dates'] > '2020-12-31'` because `df.loc['dates']` still represents your numerical data, and you can't compare those to a string.

You can use `query` which works with index:

```
df.query('date>"2020-12-31"')
```